# How to maintain the chrome style with the emojis

Tags: css

I note that the emoji look different in firefox, I think that it will the same case with the other clients or web browsers, I will like to maintain the same style that I set for chrome.

[image]

[image]

I’m making my website logo with somes emojis or html icons code.

Comment: I would suggest just making it an image instead of trying to deal with cross-browser emoji implementations.

Comment: Put a **GIF** if that works

Comment: Thank @TylerRoper I will go for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [emoji css](https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/) to achieve this - your emojis will look same everywhere.